# Can I use ACEA A5 engine oil for my engine with recommended class API SJ/SL, ILSAC GF-3?

Tags: engine, oil

According to manual for my car the recommended class of engine oil is:
"API Service SJ, SL or above, ILSAC GF-3 or above"

Can I use ACEA A5 engine oil for this engine?

Comment: This type of question has been asked on here before....

Answer (score 0):

ACEA A5 is designed for European engines. You should not use it in an engine that doesn't specifiy ACEA A5